# The best and fast way to calculate FID score

Tags: python, pytorch, evaluation, mnist, generative-adversarial-network

I created a GAN model and trained it on mnist dataset. I want to calculate fid score in each iteration. I tested torcheval library but it was so slow.
What is the best and fast way to calculate FID score for it?

Answer (score 0):

Try PyTorch-Ignite's implementation [ignite.metrics.FID](https://pytorch.org/ignite/generated/ignite.metrics.FID.html#ignite.metrics.FID).

Hope this helps!